# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: user is a required argument that is missing. Help :(

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im making a discord bot where a user can type the prefix of the bot (for example 'bonfire' here) and then a message so that it quotes it and you can look at the quote whenever you want. However There is an argument here that never gets entered and im not sure how i can make the user enter it?

```
@client.command()
async def quote(ctx,*,message:str,user):
    string=str(message)
    message_list=string.split()
    await ctx.send(message+user)
```

The problem is that because of the *message, the 'user' argument is never entered. For example the user could type bonfire quote hey everyone @example#1230, but the @example#1230 is never stored in the user variable, because every message that is sent is stored into the message variable

Comment: You can read the user first, followed by the message. `quote(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, message)`. `message` is of the type `str` by default, you do not have to manually do the conversion. Also it is not a good idea to name a variable after a keyword/import such as `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want the user to be at the end of the command, you could do something like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def quote(ctx,*, quote):
    # Get user
    try:
        mention = quote.split(" ")[-1]
        user = ctx.guild.get_member(int(mention[2:-1]))
    except Exception:
        discord.ext.commands.BadArgument("Expected Mention")
    message = " ".join(quote.split(" ")[0: -1])
    await ctx.send(message+user)
```